# Django passing json objects to jquery

Tags: jquery, django, json

in my view I am generating a json dump:

```
def myview:
    ... 
    data = list(queryset) # a query set of values
    json_dump = simplejson.dumps(data) 
    ...
    return render_to_response(request, 'results.html', { 'json_dump' : json_dump})
```

my template references a javascript file:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // some stuff involving the json_dump var
      ...
    };
```

My question is, seeing as I cannot pass `json_dump` to `$(document).ready(function()` directly, what is the best way to get the `json_dump` data into the js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you want to pass a JSON blob into your template, such that it's accessible to a JS file that's referenced from the HTML?

In which case, just set up a variable to receive the value in your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json_dump = "{{ json_dump }}"
</script>
```

And now use json_dump wherever you like in your JS.

Comment: To expand, just output the json blob to a variable inside a script tag in your template.

Comment: Doesn't the template language need to be in double quotes when used in javascript? that is var json_dump="{{ json_dump }}";

Comment: Great, I deleted my answer :)

Comment: Great. Yes - I found that this is the way to do it - the problem I have now is dealing with None values, where my js wants null (but not 'null'). Where should I tackle this - in the views or the js?

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is right, except you'll have quotes around your JSON dump which probably isn't what you want. In order to use it, you'd have to eval(json_dump), rather than just calling it as an object... I'd probably spiff it up a little like this:

```
<script>
  var window.json_dump = {{ json_dump|safe }};
</script>

<script>
  // Then later in your other javscript which comes AFTER the above script tags...
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert( window.json_dump.foo );
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Without the `|safe` modifier, the `json_dump` is unusable.